# Count in filter per item (VBA/Excel)

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, filter

I'm just working on a Macro that process a external report, this report contains 75,000 records. I need to find out a way to filter per item and sort the items based on the maximum of counts each of them has. This is an example:

[image]

Let me know if you need more details and thanks for your attention.

A good idea should be apply a filter per item in order to sort and order based on the maximum count of a value.

```
With dataSheet
    .Activate
    .Range("A1:B1").Select
    .Range("A1:B1").AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending (Instead of Descending add a count and filter based on the max count), DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With .AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Selection.AutoFilter
End With
```

Comment: Looks like a simple sort would do the job. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with an index formula but is taking forever to count every item. I'm thinking in applying an autofilter, .Range("A1:S1").AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With .AutoFilter.Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

Comment: but instead of order descending applying a formula to count in and filter based on a maximum value

Comment: When you want to add information, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52297870/edit) your question rather than using comments. It's really hard to parse code in comments

Comment: Which comes first?  the FILTER or the SORT?  Is the Filter based on some kind of aggregation? Or some rule?  The Sort in the code seems to be based only on one column-- what is that column heading?  And why is the final output seem to be sorted on two columns?

Comment: Let me edit my question and add the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This code modifies yours to get rid of `Select` and adds 2 sort keys, `Item` & `Margin`. The `Auto filter` in `column 1`, allows you to filter the individual items. You can change your worksheet to meet your needs.

```
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns(1).AutoFilter

        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & lRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B" & lRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

            .SetRange Range("A2:B" & lRow)
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
```